# Wagtail: How to override HTML tag output from database. Use <strong> or <em> instead of <b> or <i> for richtext template tag

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail, hallo-js

I am trying to have my wagtail template output `<strong></strong>` instead of `<b></b>` and `<em></em>` instead of `<i></i>`.

I manually edited the content_json values within the wagtailcore_pagerevision table records so that the `<b>` tags are `<strong>` and the `<i>` tags are `<em>` but the output HTML continues to output `<b>` and `<i>` tags respectively.

In my template I have `{{ block.value|richtext }}` for block and `{{ self.body|richtext }}` for non blocks.

The wagtail code doing the work is:

```
@register.filter
def richtext(value):
    if isinstance(value, RichText):
        # passing a RichText value through the |richtext filter should have no effect
        return value
    elif value is None:
        html = ''
    else:
        html = expand_db_html(value)

    return mark_safe('<div class="rich-text">' + html + '</div>')
```

My question is.. how can i tell Wagtail or Django to use `<strong>` and `<em>` tags?

This does not seem to be a hallo-js WYSIWYG issue or setting, but rather some sort of configuration or other setting that I cannot seem to find.

BTW.. I am using Wagtail 1.13.1 (with default Hallo editor), Django 1.11 and MySQL as the database.

To overcome my issue, i am overriding with this code..

```
# override the wagtail version and replace <b>, <i>
@register.filter(name='richtext')
def richtext(value):
    if isinstance(value, RichText):
        # passing a RichText value through the |richtext filter should have no effect
        # return value
        html = value.source
    elif value is None:
        html = ''
    else:
        html = expand_db_html(value)

    html = html.replace('<b>', '<strong>').replace('</b>', '</strong>') \
            .replace('<i>', '<em>').replace('</i>', '</em>')

    return mark_safe('<div class="rich-text">' + html + '</div>')
```

but there should be a better, more efficient way.

Comment: Hi @robnardo, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15792711/2585410), this is handled by the browser and probably hard to change. You have to manually change the tags before saving the content to the database, eg. by [overriding save method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43481981/2585410) of the page or using hooks

Comment: Hi @KonradLyda thx for the prompt reply, but as you can see in the second paragraph i have "manually edited" the records in the revision table - so the content from the database has `<strong>` and `<em>` tags.  Something is converting them on render.

Comment: are you sure you've committed the changes to the table properly? Cause I've done the same exercise (change of the <b> tag to <strong> in the database table) and the output on the website is correct. I'm using Wagtail 1.13.1 too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same issue and asked on the [Wagtail Slack](https://wagtail-slack.now.sh/) support channel. I got the advice to [register a new rich text feature](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.1/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html). The documentation shows a strikethrough example. Here are bold (strong) and italic (em):

```
import wagtail.admin.rich_text.editors.draftail.features as draftail_features
from wagtail.admin.rich_text.converters.html_to_contentstate import (
    InlineStyleElementHandler,
)


@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_strong_feature(features):
    """
    Registering the `strong` feature. It will render bold text with `strong` tag.
    Default Wagtail uses the `b` tag.
    """
    feature_name = 'strong'
    type_ = 'BOLD'
    tag = 'strong'

    # Configure how Draftail handles the feature in its toolbar.
    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'icon': 'bold',
        'description': 'Bold',
    }

    # Call register_editor_plugin to register the configuration for Draftail.
    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.InlineStyleFeature(control)
    )

    # Configure the content transform from the DB to the editor and back.
    db_conversion = {
        'from_database_format': {tag: InlineStyleElementHandler(type_)},
        'to_database_format': {'style_map': {type_: tag}},
    }

    # Call register_converter_rule to register the content transformation conversion.
    features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, db_conversion)
```

And italics with the `<em>` tag:

```
@hooks.register('register_rich_text_features')
def register_em_feature(features):
    """
    Registering the `em` feature. It will render italic text with `em` tag.
    Default Wagtail uses the `i` tag.
    """
    feature_name = 'em'
    type_ = 'ITALIC'
    tag = 'em'

    control = {
        'type': type_,
        'icon': 'italic',
        'description': 'Italic',
    }

    features.register_editor_plugin(
        'draftail', feature_name, draftail_features.InlineStyleFeature(control)
    )

    db_conversion = {
        'from_database_format': {tag: InlineStyleElementHandler(type_)},
        'to_database_format': {'style_map': {type_: tag}},
    }

    features.register_converter_rule('contentstate', feature_name, db_conversion)
```

Specify the features on your rich text fields. Don't forget to remove the old 'bold' and 'italic':

```
from wagtail.core.fields import RichTextField

class FooPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(features=['strong', 'em'])
```